# Is there any way to hide "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback." when using sys.exit() / raise SystemExit?

Tags: python, exit, sys

I'm implementing a very basic menu system in python (using Jupyter Notebook) using a function for each menu. I want to have a generic quit function that lets you exit the program from any menu. I've been using this:

```
#Function to exit the program

def quit_program():
    print("\nYou have exited the program.\nGoodbye.")
    #sys.exit(0)
    raise SystemExit from None

quit_program()
```

Which produces the following output

```
You have exited the program.
Goodbye.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

As I'm calling it deliberately I obviously know an exception has occurred so is there any way to hide that traceback option or is that part and parcel of using system exit?

Edit: Added a function call so it's reproducible e.g.

[image]

Comment: *Why* are you raising `SystemExit` explicitly rather than calling `sys.exit`?

Comment: Also, I can't duplicate this in a file that consists solely of a call to that function. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Personal preference? sys.exit() and raise SystemExit are functionally identical. I've added a function call so it's reproducible.

Comment: Can't you add a global exception handler to catch the exception and then exit appropriately?

Comment: Is this using `ipython` (that would explain the `%tb`, now that I think about it)? The result seems specific to a particular execution environment, not the code itself.

Comment: Which is to say, *Python* isn't printing the message about the exception, `ipython` is. It's catching the `SystemExit` (regardless of how it was raised), then not actually exiting. (`exit` and `quit`, which are bound to instances of `Quitter` and are intended to have interpreter-specific implementations, allow you to actually exit `ipython`.)

Comment: I'd read you shouldn't use exit and quit

Comment: "I'd read you shouldn't use exit and quit" - you are right. `exit` and `quit` should only be used in an interactive python interpreter. In a script, `sys.exit` should be used instead.